# How to select individual item in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am trying to select an individual item in a FlatList. The desired functionality is to click unfollow, and the specific item that has been clicked changes from 'unfollow' to 'follow'. So far, I have managed to complete this functionality, but the problem is that the change is made when I re-render the component manually.

Here is the code:

```
function FolloweringScreens({
    All my props here
}) {
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

  const onClickItem = (item, index) => {
    return item.isFollowed
      ? (item.isFollowed = false)
      : (item.isFollowed = true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={handleFetch}
        onEndReached={noMoreData || loadingMore ? null : handleMoreData}
        data={data}
        style={{marginTop: height * 0.07}}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles}
                underlayColor="transparent"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile page', {item})}>
                <View
                  style={styles}>

                  {User avatar and users Name components here}

                  {screen === 'Followers' ? (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          item.isFollowing
                            ? onClickItem(item, index)
                            : onClickItem(item, index);
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowing ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  ) : (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          item.isFollowed
                            ? onClickItem(item, index)
                            : onClickItem(item, index); <<<<-- This is where I am selecting the item
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowed ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default FolloweringScreens;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the prop extraData in Flatlist component ? Eg extraData={props}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by altering the inital data when the unfollow or follow button is clicked. here is the code:

```
function FolloweringScreens({
  bunch of props here,
  data,
  setfollowingData,
}) {
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setStateData(data);
  }, [data]);

    const onClickItem = (item, index) => {
    const newArrData = data.map((e, index) => {
      if (item.profileName === stateData[index].profileName) {
        item.isFollowed
          ? unfollowUser(username, item.profileName)
          : followUser(username, item.profileName);
        return {...e, isFollowed: !stateData[index].isFollowed};
      }
      return {
        ...e,
        isFollowed: true,
      };
    });
    setfollowingData(newArrData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={handleFetch}
        onEndReached={noMoreData || loadingMore ? null : handleMoreData}
        data={stateData}
        style={{marginTop: height * 0.07}}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles}
                underlayColor="transparent"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile page', {item})}>
                <View
                  style={styles}>

                  {User Avatar and User Username components here}

                  {screen === 'Followers' ? (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          // item.isFollowing
                          //   ? unfollowUser(username, item.profileName)
                          //   : followUser(username, item.profileName);
                          item.isFollowing
                            ? onClickItem(item, index)
                            : onClickItem(item, index);
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowing ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  ) : (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          // item.isFollowed
                          // ? (item.isFollowed = false)
                          // : // unfollowUser(username, item.profileName)
                          //   followUser(username, item.profileName);
                          item.isFollowed
                            ? onClickItem(item, index)
                            : onClickItem(item, index); <-This is where item is selected
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowed ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default FolloweringScreens;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where "data" comes from, but I suppose it's from the props. Trying to modify the props is a bad practice and should never be done, so I suggest to handle the data in the state, something like this:

```
function FolloweringScreens({
    All my props here
}) {
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(data);
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

  const onClickItem = (index) => {
    const stateDataCopy = [...stateData];
    stateDataCopy[index].isFollowed = !stateDataCopy[index].isFollowed;
    setStateData(stateDataCopy);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={handleFetch}
        onEndReached={noMoreData || loadingMore ? null : handleMoreData}
        data={stateData}
        style={{marginTop: height * 0.07}}
        keyExtractor={(i, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles}
                underlayColor="transparent"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile page', {item})}>
                <View
                  style={styles}>

                  {User avatar and users Name components here}

                  {screen === 'Followers' ? (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          onClickItem(index);
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowing ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  ) : (
                    <View>
                      <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        style={{marginLeft: 0}}
                        onPress={() => {
                          onClickItem(index);
                        }}>
                        {item.isFollowed ? (
                          <Text>Unfollow</Text>
                        ) : (
                          <Text>Follow</Text>
                        )}
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default FolloweringScreens;
```

Probably this exact code will not work, but the idea here is that you store your data in the local state and modify the "isFollowed" value of that state data when clicking on the item.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately when going with this approach, my screen does not load in the state data. When i console log stateData, it receive an empty array twice

Comment: Also, you are correct. My data comes as a prop from the parent component

Comment: stateData is initialized with the value of data, so if you are seeing an empty array then maybe it's because the data prop is an empty array?

Comment: Im not quite sure. Also, I wanted to ask, why is trying to modify the props a bad practice? thank you

Comment: Props are read-only, you can see why here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Comment: I understand. In that case, I have changed my code to store the data in the component state with a useeffect. Could you have a look and see if it is the best way to go about this functionality? Thank you